# unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: postfix, openssl, self-signed

I use openssl to create a self signed CA cert on ubuntu gnome 16.04, and use this CA cert to sign a cert for postfix and httpd, but when using tls to connect postfix, the command was:

```
openssl s_client -connect xiedeacc.com:587 -starttls smtp
```

it will complaint

and it returns:

```
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
```

but when changing the command to

```
openssl s_client -connect xiedeacc.com:587 -starttls smtp -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/xiedeaccca.crt
```

the output was all right, no problem, so I guess it's openssl s_client cannot find this self signed CA, but chrome can visit this CA signed website after I manually import it into chrome cert root list. So, how to import it to Ubuntu's certificate root list but not just Chrome's root cert list ? Does Ubuntu store CA certs like windows?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

To import your self-signed CA to Ubuntu's certificate root list, you have to configure `ca-certificates`:

---

First, make a directory called `/usr/share/ca-certificates/extra`:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra`
```

Then, copy your CA certificate to the directory:

```
sudo cp /etc/ssl/certs/xiedeaccca.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/xiedeaccca.crt
```

Finally, reconfigure `ca-certificates`:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

Press `Space` to select your self signed CA certs, and you should be done.

---

Comment: thanks, that's what I exactly need, but there still a problem, now, my self CA certs was on reconfigure list,  how to choosen my self CA, I have tried enter, or press M, Y, all failed,

Comment: What do you actually mean? Post your terminal output by editing your question.

Comment: notice, though my CA cert was on list, but it wasn't choosen, I tried enter M, Y to choose it, all failed?

Comment: I just edited: Press space to select.